# Making array of checkbox and numberpicker using java in eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, checkbox, numberpicker

I am trying to make an array of checkboxes using java in Eclipse. I tried this code from someone, but it didn't work. It said: 
"The constructor CheckBox (string) is undefined" (for the fourth line). 
What am I supossed to do?

`List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
        String labels[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(labels[i]);
            checkboxes.add(checkbox); //for further use you add it to the list
        }`

I'm also looking for ways to create array of numberpicker using java in Eclipse, but I still haven't found the way. Can anybody help me?
Thank you.

Comment: is `CheckBox` your own class or is it something of the library?

Comment: @Blip It's from the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code as suggested by the answer of Suspended. I am providing you with the details:

```
List<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>(); 
//changed CheckBox to JCheckBox above
String labels[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}; 
for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) { 
   JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox(labels[i]); 
   //Declared and initialised JCheckBox instead of CheckBox
   checkboxes.add(checkbox); 
   //for further use you add it to the list 
}
```

also remember to `import javax.swing.JCheckBox;`

Comment: Okay, so I have to download and import the java library for JCheckBox to Eclipse workspace, then import it to my android project? Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

Change CheckBox for JCheckBox.
Voilla :)

Comment: it said: "JCheckBox cannot be resolved to a type" now.
Anyway, whats the difference between the two? sorry I'm new to programming. Thanks

Comment: @CynthiaAnggraeni they belong to two different packages CheckBox is awt component and JCheckBox is a swing component